# Get selected text's html in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with contentEditable set to true.
I have to find selected text html. I am able to get selected text in Firefox by:

```
window.getSelection();
```

In case of IE, I am able to get selected text html by using:

```
document.selection.createRange()
```

But, how can I find selected text html in Firefox?

Comment: What do you mean by an editable div?

Comment: Shorten that to...What do you mean?

Comment: @Will Apologies, when i flagged it the question didn't make sense at all, it was originally phrased badly though it's been cleaned up now.

Comment: @GordonCarpenter-Thompson: Don't ever forget, anybody can suggest edits, no matter their rep.  And asking OP for clarification (as you did) is always better than pulling the trigger on a flag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select text and store it in variable called `mytext`.

```
if (!window.x) {
    x = {};
}
x.Selector = {};
x.Selector.getSelected = function() {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}

$(function() {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
        var mytext = x.Selector.getSelected();
        alert(mytext);
    });
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/YstZn/1/

Comment: `x.Selector.getSelected()` returns a `Selection` object in most browsers and a string containing the selected text in IE <= 8. Neither of those things is the selected HTML, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Tim Down is right, this answer doesn't work. Tim's answer below does work.

Answer (score 31):

To get the selected HTML as a string, you can use the following function:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver!! Big up!!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Best solution I've found for getting html and text from editable div. Great to use for injecting HTML tags into the selected content (for example, if they're using your div as a form and they want to make some of their text bold)

Comment: This almost literally saved my life (and my sanity too!) Great starting point for what I need

Answer (score 2):

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

It returns a document fragment. It contains the nodes where the selection begins and ends and some other juicy stuff. Inspect it with FireBug or another JavaScript console, &&|| for more info

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.getSelection

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN:

> "A Selection object, when cast to string, either by appending an empty
> string ("") or using Selection.toString(), returns the text selected."

For me, any of the following work in Chrome 86:

```
String(window.getSelection())
window.getSelection() + ""
window.getSelection().toString()
String(document.getSelection())
document.getSelection() + ""
document.getSelection().toString()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.link').click(function(){
        var mytext = getSelected();
        alert(mytext);
    })

function getSelected() {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

to get the text of a div you do this:(in jQuery)

```
var text = $('div.selector').text();
```

Comment: I think he means if he highlights some of the text in a div, how can he get the test that is highlighted.