# how to get highlighted/selection data from a users browser using php/javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

is there any way to get highlighted or selected text data from a user using php or javascript? I am building a text editor and need to use a callback function to bold/highlight/underline/etc selected text. thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [get selected text's html in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669448/get-selected-texts-html-in-div)

Comment: Please learn the difference between Java and JavaScript.

Comment: iv been using google but every time i searched php and nothing came up. and i now the difference, I accidently tagged java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `<textarea>`:

```
txtarea.textLength;
txtarea.selectionStart;
txtarea.selectionEnd;
```

for elements like `<div>` etc. check this tutorial http://www.webreference.com/js/column12/crossbrowser.html

you may like to check this powerful and simple javascript text editor - [TinyCME](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Comment: thanks! this helped, appreciate you actually answering and not being a smart*** like two of those guys^^. I know this was probably a really noobish question.