# Copying text from page doesn't preserve line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I need to be able to preserve line breaks in text displayed on a web page when using a highlight+right click context menu function for a chrome extension.

So the text is displayed like this

```
Some information on one line
Some on the next line
Then some on the last line
```

When I highlight it and execute my function, it all gets put into the same line like this

```
Some information on one line Some on the next line Then some on the last line
```

Is there any way I can preserve the line spaces when processing my highlighted text in javascript?

Here's my code I'm using to grab the highlighted text:

```
// Set up context menu at install time.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var context = "selection";
  var title = "Get Text";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                       "id": "context" + context});  
});

// add click event
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

// The onClicked callback function.
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  var message = info.selectionText;
  console.log(message);
};
```

Comment: If you have control of the display, can you insert \r\n where it's needed?  This would add line breaks in JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, is the text isn't always going to be the same so I'm not always going to know where to put the line breaks.

Comment: Right, but there are dynamic ways to do this in most server-side languages, some sort of Replace() method.  Search for the line break character and add /r/n after that, or something to that effect.

Comment: The problem is that my string has no line breaks in it. The variable `message` is one long string.

Comment: Is the content controllable by you, as to what's displaying on the page in the first place?  Or are you hoping to click on any web page on the internet and have the line breaks preserved.

Comment: Basically the latter.

Comment: Might be some more useful info here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996540/recognize-multple-lines-on-info-selectiontext-from-context-menu

Comment: If there was a way that I could get the element that the text was in, in jquery or something... that would probably work.

Comment: I think you can inject a content script code into the active tab with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` and access the selection object the way it's done in the linked answer.

Comment: Basically, you're getting `window.getSelection().toString()` here, which does not take into account while nodes make the line break. It's going to be complex.. Seano666's link provides a way to extract HTML instead of plaintext, but reducing that to plaintext is non-trivial.