# Position of selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find the position of the selected text in a div. I prompt the user to select a substring of the text in a div and then submit it. I need the index of the start point and end point and have not been successful using the strategy below. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the function I have and it is not working:

```
if (typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined') {                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
var sel = window.getSelection();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
startOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
endOffset = startOffset + range.toString().length;
}
```

The div is called "myarea".  Thanks

Comment: Which line "isn't working"? Is your `if` condition true? Does any line throw an error? Are you getting back numeric values for your range, but they're different than expected (e.g., `-1`, `0`)?

Comment: Possibly related and helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669448/get-selected-texts-html-in-div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it right!
Its the `startOffset` which is causing it not to work.
Currently it is:

```
var startOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
```

The value on the RHS which is `preCaretRange.toString().length` is going to return you the total length of the string which has been selected, and *not* the start position. To get the start position you would use the `startOffset` property stored *by* the range. Therefore:

```
var startOffset = preCaretRange.startOffset;
```

**A note on optimization:** you do not need to clone `range` into `preCaretRange.`.

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    if (typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined') {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

        var startOffset = range.startOffset;
        var endOffset = startOffset + range.toString().length - 1;

        console.log("Selection starts at: " + startOffset);
        console.log("Selection ends at: " + endOffset);
    }
}, false);
```

Here is a fiddle which demonstrates it working with an actual text selection: http://jsfiddle.net/Dp3qp/3/

Comment: This works for the startoffset but not for the end offset.. it gives a larger index than the actual index.

Comment: so it works for the first selection, but not the following selections.

Comment: if you are looking for an inclusive end range then `endOffset` will simply have to be changed to `endOffset - 1`

Comment: i tested it with multiple selections and it seemed to be okay, can you please elaborate more on your test input?

Comment: Sure, so I am using it to select the text in the div "myarea" then click a button to record the selection, then select again. The selection for the first time always works, however.. the following selections are always incorrect.

Comment: ok so you want a button which can be clicked on to reveal the selection, i made another fiddle here replicating that: http://jsfiddle.net/gjKXH/ let me know if this is what you need

Comment: thank you for your help. I already have the button that reveals the selection. Your method works great if I am making 1 selection. However my interface involves selecting and clicking a button, and selecting again and clicking a button. It does not give the correct index the second time. Here is the website http://54.244.121.67/index.php

Comment: It was a browser issue. I had a plug-in that was splitting the content in my divs. This totally worked. Thanks!!!