# count no of nodes in a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

here if i select some 3 or 4 lines on browser then i want the no of  of the     selection on browser i.e. count selected  `<span>`

I have an example.html which includes following code then,

```
<div id="p">
<p id="p1">
    <span>wefwef wefwefsdfc fcsdcs wefwscsdc qwefwcsdc </span>
    <span>wefwec acvsdc wecfsdc <br />asdcsdc sdcdc wedwed</span>
    <span> wefwec acvsdc wecfsdc asdcsdc sdcdc</span>
    <span> wefwec acvsdc wecfsdc<br /> asdcsdc sdcdc</span>
    <span>wefwec acvsdc wecfsdc asdcsdc sdcdc</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span>wefwef wefwefsdfc fcsdcs wefwscsdc qwefwcsdc </span>
    <span>wefwec acvsdc wecfsdc <br />asdcsdc sdcdc wedwed</span>
    <span> wefwec acvsdc wecfsdc asdcsdc sdcdc</span>
    <span> wefwec acvsdc wecfsdc<br /> asdcsdc sdcdc</span>
</p>
</div>
```

I have the following questions:

1. how to count selected `<span>` ?
2. how will i get no of selected `<span>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669448/get-selected-texts-html-in-div

Answer (score 1):

You can get the HTML of the selection with a code similar to this one:

```
function getSelectedHTML () {
    var result = '';
    var range;
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        result = range.htmlText;
    }
    else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
            result = div.innerHTML;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

After that, it's a matter of parsing the selection.  One way would be with jQuery:

```
var count = $('span', $(getSelectedHTML())).length;
```

Comment: thanks.above code gave result only in case if we select lines of multiple <p> tag if we selects lines from single <p> tag then it always results to 0 i.e. zero

Comment: thank you very much by putting outerHTMl i got expected output

Comment: @KomalKhatkole If you're still having issues, it's probably because the selected HTML isn't fully formed (i.e. you're selecting from the middle of a `span`.  You can easily checked this - and add `<span>` in the beginning or `</span>` at the end to make it complete.