# Capturing "Selstart", "Sel..end" within a non-input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I'm setting up a table, formatted like this.. Please forgive the silly sample data. All of this is actually loaded with json, but the output looks like this:

```
<table id="famequotes">
<tr><td id="par001">It was the best of times, it was the worst of times.</td></tr>
<tr><td id="par002">Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe</td></tr>
<tr><td id="par003">In the jungle, the mighty jungle, the lion sleeps tonight...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Using mousedown on $("#famequotes td"), and mouseup, I can allow users to highlight text and capture the start and end row, and similarly capture all the rows in between with onmouseover.

What I want to do is capture the SelStart of the start row (the table cell I started highlighting from) and the sel...stop of the last row.

I have not been able to find an answer, though I have researched and google searched already.

### MIchal Hainc's answer is really cool, but not what I am seeking.

I can see how the selection box could be useful, and I would love to incorporate it.

However, what I'm actually seeking is so that if the user highlights text as I've highlighted in http://jsfiddle.net/vhyyzeog/1/ it would return 3 for selStart and 12 for selEnd. I'm already tracking the first highlighted row, and the last, so I know what rows to apply selstart and selend to.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this question elsewhere on Stack's site. It's not as pretty and perfect as I'd imagined it might be.

Source: [Hussein's answer to "Get selected text's html in div"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670157/3917091)

Here's sort of the groundwork for how you can obtain useful data from this, if you want more than the basic selected text.

http://jsfiddle.net/YstZn/541/

```
if (!window.x) {
    x = {};
}

x.Selector = {};
x.Selector.getSelected = function() {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    console.log(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode);
    console.log(window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode);
    return t;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
        var mytext = x.Selector.getSelected();
        alert(mytext);
    });
});
```

It's not quite what I'd imagined, but it definitely provides the elements I need to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 1):

I have constructed a fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/jra9ttot/16/

I have used jQuery UI widget "selectable"... the javascript is like this:

You can select like in windows explorer... drag a lasso with the mouse over your table cells, it will 
select multiple...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#famequotes').selectable({
            filter: 'td',
             start: function (event, ui) {
                $('#log').append('<div>selction start: ' + $(event.toElement).attr('id') + '</div>');
            },
            selected: function (event, ui) {
                $('#log').append('<div>selected item: ' + $(ui.selected).attr('id') + '</div>');
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                var lastSelElem = $('#famequotes').find('td.ui-selected').last();
                 $('#log').append('<div>selection end: ' + $(lastSelElem).attr('id') + '</div>');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, and this is wonderful, but it's not what I'm seeking. I amended my question. Voted up for the effort though, and because it helps me solve a different problem.