# jQuery event to detect deselection of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there such an event captured by jQuery that I can use to detect the deselection of text **after** the text has been deselected? So far I've been using a way in which I capture the click on the document's BODY, but the click(or mouseup) get the selection of text before the text is cleared (by clicking somewhere else in the document, once).

Also, is there an event that fires after the user selected some text in the page? The method above works successfully because, apparently, the click event on the body is fired after the text has been selected. But I would like a cleaner way.

Note: this operation is done on a DIV, not on an an INPUT or TEXTAREA element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) - object represents the range of text selected by the user or the current position. Your question already answered into Stacks:

[get selected text's html in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669448/get-selected-texts-html-in-div)

There's, the solution is create a prototype to improve browser's compatibility and stuff. This works too, but I recommend the solution of the link above:

EDIT: You can store the AnchorOffset and the FocusOffset into a session if they are in a range and compare after that, simple

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("mouseup", function() {
        var mytext = window.getSelection();
        if (typeof sessionStorage.getItem('initialRange') != 'undefined' && (mytext.anchorOffset != sessionStorage.getItem('initialRange') || mytext.focusOffset != sessionStorage.getItem('finalRange'))){
            //DO WHAT YOU WANT, THE TEXT HAS BEEN DESELECTED
        }
        //take the coordenates of mouseup, when the mouse create a range, store the values
        if (mytext.anchorOffset != mytext.focusOffset){
            sessionStorage.setItem('initialRange', mytext.anchorOffset);
            sessionStorage.setItem('finalRange', mytext.focusOffset);
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: Next time, I'll read better :)

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl!

Comment: There's nothing to search and I'm already using this method as specified in the OP. You didn't even answer my initial question about event deselection. Next time, take your time to read.