# How to get selection positions relative to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `textarea` containing HTML, and a `div` rendering this HTML.
What I'd like to do is getting the selection positions (`start` and `end`) in the `innerHTML` whenever I select text **either in the `textarea` or in the `div`**.

I already managed to get the positions when I select text in the `textarea` (as there are easy ways to do it for either `textarea` or `input`), but I struggle with the `div` part.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670825/7831383) helped me getting the selected HTML, but there are two problems with this:

- If the same piece of HTML is present twice, using `string.indexOf` to get the position will always get me the position of the first occurrence
- Whenever I select a part of an element (may it be `<li>`, `<u>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, etc), the function adds the corresponding tag, so the selected HTML does not match the `innerHTML`.

  - Say if I select `tu</b></li><li><i>Pi` in the example below, I will get ***`<li><b>`***`tu</b></li><li><i>Pi`***`</i></li>`*** instead.

```js
updateDiv();

function updateDiv() {
  $("#myDiv").html($("#myArea").val());
}

function myTest() {
  var html = "";    

  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }

  if(html.length > 0)
    alert(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id='myArea' onchange='updateDiv();' rows='12', cols='40'>
  <ol>
    <li>Patata</li>
    <li>
      Petete
      <ul>
        <li><b>Pututu</b></li>
        <li><i>Pititi</i></li>
        <li>Pututu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</textarea>

<div id='myDiv' onclick='myTest()'>
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to perform actions on the content of my `textarea` based on the selected HTML (hence why I need to get the selection position relative to the `div` `innerHTML`).

Comment: Maybe giving the div the `contentEditable` attribute could help (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) -- but your user could change the text and you'd have to change it back.  There's no way to know which occurrence of a substring is selected unless you have access to the base string (ie the whole string), but maybe there's a way to get position of the cursor within an editable div? Or, you could use a second `textarea` instead of a div, maybe with the `disabled` or `readonly` attribute (if these don't break your use case) , or just adding div-like styling.

Comment: Woah! In fact using `contentEditable` might even be better than what I planned to do! Let me just try to see if I can get the position with this :)

Comment: Ok so I didn't manage to get the position with the `div` (so the question still holds), but I can toggle bold, italic, underline on the selected text, so it's quite good already, thanks! :)

Comment: @Rafalon the user only should seleted the HTML render or div content as well?

Comment: @x-rw The purpose was for the user to be able to edit the HTML content in either a user-friendly way (select text and tick bold/italic/underline or add bullet lists for example) or a more advanced way (add tags as needed). Therefore, in the end, both rendered and raw HTML should be editable. tl;dr: the user should be able to select both HTML render and div content